# Does $\sup\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$ provided $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly (or pointwise)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

> Does $\sup\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$ provided $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly (or pointwise)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Pointwise: no. Uniformly yes.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you think of a counterexample for the pointwise case? Why doesn't this work in the uniform case?

Comment: Hi, I have not studied analysis for 5 years. I almost forget everything in analysis. Can you help me?

Comment: Then perhaps it is worth reviewing the definitions of pointwise and uniform convergence.

Comment: I tried but it does not work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointwise case: Take $f_n : [0,1] \to \{0,1\}$ defined by $f_n(x) = 1$ if $0 < x \le 1/n$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f = 0$. However, $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} | f_n(x) - f(x) | = 1$ for all $n$.

Uniform case: If $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then for all $\epsilon$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, and all $x \in [a,b]$,
$$| f_n(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon.$$

In this case, we certainly have
$$\sup_{x \in [a,b]} | f_n(x) - f(x) | \le \epsilon.$$

So we do have $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} | f_n(x) - f(x) | \to 0$.

Comment: Many thanks, I have one more question. If $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $g_n\to g$ uniformly. Does it imply that $f_n\circ g_n \to f\circ g$?

Comment: This is not related to the original question. You should post this as a separate question.